# How to display the content of 2D <String> array in list view under the same horizontal line?

Tags: android, arrays, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have the following code:

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[][] from ={{"jonathan","guillaume","gerard"},{"fraise","patate","chocolat"}};

        ArrayAdapter<String[][]> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String[][]>(getListView().getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, from);

        getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

XML is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="zathstudio.projetliste.MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>
```

I'm trying to get the "from" array to display inside the listView using an arrayAdapter. it works if the array is unidimensionnal but how can can I do it with a 2D array ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom ArrayAdapter inherited from the ArrayAdapter class. I find this is also easiest to do with an ArrayList of objects from your own class rather than an array, but I'm assuming both are possible. I've only implemented this with the ArrayList structure though.

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<YourClass> objects;
    //or with 2d array this might work:
    private String [][] strings2d;

    public CustomArrayAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<YourClass> objects) {
        super(context, -1, objects);
        this.context = context;
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //Get individual object to be displayed
        YourClass object = this.objects.get(position);
        //or with 2d array
        String[] strings1d = this.strings2d[position];

        String string1 = object.strings[1];  //Your class has array of strings as class var
        String string2 = object.strings[2];
        String string3 = object.strings[3];

        //Inflate view and get (custom) layout for each item in list 
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View customView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_custom_list_item_layout, parent, false);

        //Get textView to display each String
        TextView textView1 = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.text_field_1);
        TextView textView2 = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.text_field_2);
        TextView textView3 = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.text_field_2);

        //Set text of each textView
        textView1.setText(string1);
        textView1.setText(string2);
        textView1.setText(string3);

        //Or with 2d arrays
        textView1.setText(strings1d[0]);
        textView1.setText(strings1d[1]);
        textView1.setText(strings1d[2]);

        return customView;
    }

}
```

I haven't tested this to see if it runs and obviously you'd need to create a custom class to hold the strings and a custom layout to display each item in the ListView.